# TestNG failures which aren't failures

Tags: java, testng, ui-testing

I have added a complex UI testing framework executed via TestNG to a large scale enterprise application that we don't own (we are users).

The test framework resolves data from the system suitable for testing using a query builder; sometimes that data is out of date and it throws expected exceptions. These exceptions mean that the test cannot complete, but hasn't really failed.

I am looking for a way to abort that individual test rather than failing it. The test is executed (with minor changes) around 6 times each build, so I'm not concerned if 1-2 abort for each build, but need to silence the aborts, which are currently marked as failures; is there any option other than causing them to pass, which seems like a poor choice?

Comment: Try this: http://konigsberg.blogspot.co.il/2007/11/testng-and-expectedexceptions-ive.html          @Test(expectedExceptions = PlaneFullException.class)

Comment: @ran I don't believe Expected Exceptions works because they require it to occur and I just want to make it quiet when they do occur (10-20% of the time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two more options :)  These would help mark the test as skipped instead of failed or passed

1. catch the exception you are expecting and throw a SkipException from your @Test methods
   Or
2. Implement IInvokedMethodListener and in the afterInvocation method
   do something like

   public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {

   ```
   if(testResult.getThrowable().getClass().equals(YourExceptionClass.class))
        testResult.setStatus(TestResult.SKIP);
   ```

   }

Comment: Working perfectly, this is exactly what I was after!

Answer (score 0):

For sure. You can chose to skip the failing tests or ignore them out right.

For that you will need a class that implements IMethodInterceptor.

I can't paste any code I am using for obvious reasons, but take a look here for an example on how to use the IMethodInterceptor: https://gist.github.com/krmahadevan/5028960

You didn't mention on your question, but if you are using Jenkins then you can pass parameters to the build, which can then be used to filter the tests you are trying to skip/ignore.

Comment: Unfortunately the IMethodInterceptor isn't appropriate because it requires you to know what will fail before hand. A critical part of the test performed inline is the querying of the test data from existing real production data. Therefore we cannot know until the test instance is running if it will data-fail (data dependent failure) which doesn't really indicate a test failure, but only the inability to run the test properly with the data the test resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Use try-catch to handle the acceptable exception in your test class. If you catch the exception and don't have any asserts that fail, the test will pass.

Comment: I'm chasing a third route to pass/fail that allows me to note that it didn't run as expected, but not show up as a failure; I think what you're suggesting may well be my only option though